# SQL only working with chunks of full code

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query:

```
/*Purple Achievement*/
ALTER TABLE NATCHTest2 DROP total;
INSERT INTO NATCHTest2 SELECT * From Points WHERE Silver_Purple ='Purp-20' AND Class_Subset ='RZ';
INSERT INTO NATCHTest2 SELECT * From Points WHERE Silver_Purple ='B-10' AND Class_Subset ='CCZ';
INSERT INTO NATCHTest2 SELECT * From Points WHERE Silver_Purple ='Purp-10' AND Class_Subset ='JZ';

ALTER TABLE NATCHTest2 ADD total VARCHAR(10);

INSERT INTO NATCHTest

SELECT   Hgt,RegNum,Callname,OLastname,Type,Points,Class,Total_Points,Title,Platinum,
Silver_Purple,MAX(Date_Earned),Judge,HostClub,DRI,Class_Subset,IncorrectRegNum,MemNum,
ID, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM     NATCHTest2
GROUP BY RegNum;

DELETE From NATCHTest WHERE total <6;

UPDATE NATCHTest
SET Hgt ='',Callname='',OLastname='',Type='',Points='',Class='',Total_Points='',Title='',Platinum='',Silver_Purple='',
Judge='',HostClub='Purple Achievement Cup',DRI='',Class_Subset='A-PC01',ID='';

ALTER TABLE NATCHTest DROP total;
INSERT INTO Points SELECT * From NATCHTest;
ALTER TABLE NATCHTest ADD total VARCHAR(10);
TRUNCATE TABLE NATCHTest;
TRUNCATE TABLE NATCHTest2;
```

If I run it piece by piece, it works perfectly.  But when I try to run the entire thing it never inserts the record into the Points database.

I know it's pretty ugly, but it does work, just not as a whole.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: After all these `ALTER` statements, do the tables `Points` and NATCHTest` have the exact same column layout? When doing `INSERT INTO ...SELECT` you should be explicit about the column order instead of `SELECT *`. That is, `INSERT INTO Points (col1, col2, colN) SELECT col1, col2, colN FROM NATCHTEST`

Comment: And with what client are you running it? If there is an error or warning, that should be recoverable somehow in your client.

Comment: The column layout is exactly the same. I will try changing the insert and see if that helps.

Comment: Could it be that all "total" values are < 6 in NACTHTest? Have you tried seeing what's in NACTHTest (remove the truncate)?

Comment: Negatory on that one.   I have ran the entire thing, piece by piece.  And everything ends up working correctly just how I expect it to.  But when I try to run the whole thing I get no errors, but no data in the end location either.